# How to print multiple orders String on a receipt page in one variable in java

Tags: java

My number one problem here is in the receipt page. When I order from the menu, it prints in the receipt but when I order the same/another order in the same menu(i.e I order first food in Chicken page menu then my second order is another or same food but in the same Chicken page menu), the last order will be print on the receipt page. What code I will use to print multiple orders even if I order in the same menu. Here's my code in my receipt page:

```
     System.out.println("\n\t\t\t  BT-RET FOOD CORPORATION"
                + "\n\t\t\t  Ayala Blvd Ermita Manila"
                + "\n\t\t\tVAT Reg TIN: 000-000-000-001\n"
                + "       \t\t\t" + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())
                + "\n+--------------------------------------------------------------+"
                + "\n| Cashier: " + name1 + "                                   |"
                + "\n| Official Receipt #:                                          |"
                + "\n+--------------------------------------------------------------+");
      if(counttc!=0){
          do{
          System.out.println("\t" + chickn + "\t\t\t" + chickprice);}
          while(counttc==count);}
      if(counttbu!=0){
          do{
          System.out.println("\t" + burgn + "\t\t\t" + burgprice);}
          while(counttbu==count);}
      if(counttr!=0){
          do{
          System.out.println("\t" + rmn + "\t\t\t" + rmprice);}
          while(counttr==count);}
      if(counttn!=0){
          do{
          System.out.println("\t" + noodn + "\t\t\t" + noodprice);}
          while(counttn==count);}
      if(countts!=0){
          do{
          System.out.println("\t" + sann + "\t\t\t" + sanprice);}
          while(countts==count);}
      if(counttbr!=0){
          do{
          System.out.println("\t" + brean + "\t\t\t" + breaprice);}
          while(counttbr==count);}
      if(counttd!=0){
          do{
          System.out.println("\t" + ddn + "\t\t\t" + ddprice);}
          while(counttd==count);}
      if(countta!=0){
          do{
          System.out.println("\t" + addn + "\t\t\t" + addprice);}
          while(countta==count);}
      if(counttk!=0){
          do{
          System.out.println("\t" + kidn + "        " + kidprice);}
          while(counttk==count);}




      System.out.print("\n\tDelivery                    " + dec1.format(deli)
    +"\n\t12% VAT                       " + dec1.format(vat)
    +"\n\tAmount Due                    " + dec1.format(runningTotal)
    +"\n\tCash                      " + dec1.format(cash)
    +"\n\tChange                        " + dec1.format(change));
      System.out.println("\n\n\t\t\tThis serves as your Official Receipt."
      +"\n\t\t\t\t   12% VAT Included"
      +"\n\t\t\tPrices inclusive of 10% delivery charge"
      +"\n\t\t\t   Thank you, and please come again.");


}
```

}

Comment: It's difficult to understand what's your problem, throwing 100s lines of code doesn't help.

Comment: Try to break it down for us, to see more clearly, you should write your code in a more OO way, meaning, if your app deals with orders, menues, receipt, you should probably have an Order, and a Receipt class some where. If your Receipt is about several orders, then you should have a Collection<Order> somewhere.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I edited just by now and I paste my receipt code there. I'm a newbie.